# How can I keep a part in the air while not freezing body angular velocity?

Tags: roblox

I need to apply body angular velocity so that the part can rotate while being suspended in the air. I've 
tried:

body velocity set to 0, 0, 0,

anchors,

rope constraints,

and welds,

but that freezes the body angular velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `BodyAngularVelocity` to accomplish rotation, and `BodyPosition` to keep its position, even in the air:

```
local part = script.Parent

local bodyPosition = Instance.new("BodyPosition", part)
bodyPosition.Position = Vector3.new(0, 5, 0)
bodyPosition.MaxForce = Vector3.new(1000000,1000000,1000000)

local gyro = Instance.new("BodyGyro", part)
gyro.CFrame = CFrame.Angles(0, 0, 0)

local bodyVelocity = Instance.new("BodyAngularVelocity", part)
bodyVelocity.AngularVelocity = Vector3.new(0, 1, 0)
```

The BodyPosition will attempt to keep it at position (0,5,0) using a strong force. The BodyGyro will keep it from rotating on the x and z axis. The BodyAngular velocity rotates it at a slow speed around the y axis.